# How to open Windows apps folder in explorer

Tags: windows-8.1

I want to get access to the following folder:

**C:\Program Files\WindowsApps**

But i get the following error:

http://www.4shared.com/download/xGge5eZaba/Screenshot__66_.png?lgfp=3000

I have searched the internet and told me to press continue,so i pressed it and got an error,
And then i pressed on the "security tab" link but as said i must see the security tab, but there is no security tab for me there:

http://www.4shared.com/download/KnkBV1yoba/Screenshot__68_.png?lgfp=3000

1. what i must do to make it revealed?
2. Is there an alternative explorer that can explore this folder without this permission?

(Sorry for uploading pictures in file hosting site,i don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a system message so any other File Browser like Total Commander would either throw an other error or just simply do nothing.

This is something about permissions. You don't have the permission to open this folder, oth folder for example are user folders of other users on our system: you simply can't access them so easily.
I have tried this now and this is the advanced security tab i'll get [image]

Try another file browser as administrator (right click --> open as administrator)
I have tried it yet, also windows explorer in administration mode won't give you access, you have to add permissions for your user. But i can't figure out why you don't have a security tab, otherwise you could follow [this instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Metro-Style-Apps-Installation-Folder-in-Windows-8).